# Сочетания клавиш

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys, клавиатура

Как на форме обработать сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, даже если, фокус установлен не на самой форме? (Что-то, связанное с `PreviewKey` вроде...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оконная процедура не получит сообщений о каком-либо вводе, если окно не находится в фокусе.
Смотри API функции RegisterHotKey и UnregisterHotKey.
Пример: [How to Register Hotkey for Three key combination using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970978/how-to-register-hotkey-for-three-key-combination-using-c-sharp).

---

Для обработки ввода для всех контролов в одном обработчике есть свойство [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)

Comment: @Flammable, я имел ввиду, если например, пользователь перед нажатием сочетания кликнул по панели или листбоксу.

Comment: Такое тоже можно. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Это конечно всё здорово, но на **`MSDN`** я и сам мог зайти (что и сделал).

Comment: Прекрасно, зачем тогда вопрос задавать? Других проверить?

Comment: Эмм... вопрос я задал т. к. я не понял как это сделать даже, посмотрев на MSDN.

Comment: Читать пробовал? Там даже примеры для детей есть, не разобраться невозможно.